# C# change desktop wallpaper with winapi

Tags: c#, wallpaper

I'd like to change my desktop wallpaper. To do so I've written following code, but it doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Background bg = new Background();
        bg.DoSomething();  
    }
}

class Background
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam,
        string pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    private const uint SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0014;
    private const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    private const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

    private string pathtofiles;
    private string[] filename;
    private int count, o, ui;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public Background()
    {
        pathtofiles = @"C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\Test\";
        filename = new string[150];
        count = 0;
        o = 0;
        ui = 0;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\Test\");
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in ParentDirectory.GetFiles())
        {

            if (f.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"))
            {
                filename[count] = f.Name;
                count++;
            }
            if (f.Name.EndsWith(".png"))
            {
                filename[count] = f.Name;
                count++;
            }
            if (f.Name.EndsWith(".bmp"))
            {
                filename[count] = f.Name;
                count++;
            }
        }

        count = 0;

        foreach (string s in filename)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathtofiles + s))
            {
                System.IO.Stream BitmapStream = System.IO.File.Open(pathtofiles + s, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(BitmapStream);
                System.Drawing.Bitmap mBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img);
                mBitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\BmpSpeichern\00" + o + ".bmp");
                o++;


            }
        }
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\BmpSpeichern\");
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in ParentDirectory2.GetFiles())
            {

                if (f.Name.EndsWith(".bmp"))
                {
                    filename[count] = f.Name;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, @"C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\BmpSpeichern\" + filename[ui],
                        SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

First I copy the image files to another directory then convert them to .bmp data type. Works perfectly but the call to the WINAPI function SystemParametersInfo fails to change the wallpaper. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me.... If you get a black wallpaper, make sure the file paths are correct.

Comment: Is your app 32 or 64 bit? This may be problem with P/Invoke, BTW http://www.windows-commandline.com/change-windows-wallpaper-command-line/ (you may change wallpaper by manipulating registry w/o WinAPI)

Comment: my os is win 7 64 bit

Comment: my application I think it's 32 bit how do I know?

Comment: when I set the path to the image file with `using(var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true))
                    {
                        key.SetValue("Wallpaper", @"C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\BmpSpeichern\" + filename[ui]);
                    }` I can see the image in the preview window when you go to desktop right click where you can change desktop wallpaper screensaver and so on but nothing changes on my desktop Do I have to restart PC?